# FOSRestBundle Controller as a service not working

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, fosrestbundle

I'm developing an api with symphony a fosrestbundle. I also want to use constructor injection in my controllers like I always do to inject some EntityRepository.

The problem is that this injection is not working, I get an error that says that a repository was expected but none was given.

I figured out something: FOSRestBundle generates some url automatically, but if I want to use constructor injection, this urls have to use the name of the service I created for my controller. For instance, if my controller service is defined like this:

## services.yml

```
dnd_agent_controller:
    class: DnD\RaHApiBundle\Controller\AgentController
    arguments: ["@dnd_agent_repository"]
```

Then my routes have to be defined like this:

## routing.yml

```
agents_resource:
  path: /agents
  defaults: { _controller: dnd_agent_controller:getallAction}
```

Notice the _controller field, it's using the service name defined above, not the namespacebundle:controller:action like always.

With this configuration, my constructor injection works, however this is a problem for me since this urls are being generated automatically by the FOSRestBundle and I like that.

Is there a way to use both, constructor injection in my controllers and FOSRestBundle? How would I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use FOSRestBundle routing style but with the service name.

**Routing**
eg.

```
agents_resource:
    type: rest
    resource: dnd_agent_controller
```

**EDIT**: Blog post with example http://blog.dashboardhub.io/2015/09/26/symfony-controller-not-extending-fosrest-bundle/